# Neo4j add property to relationship when using apoc.merge.relationship()

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have the following import:

```
// NO ATTACHMENT OR LINK
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM ("file:///sessions/Hourly_Parsed/2019-12-10_00_hourly_parsed_mail_logs.csv") AS row
MERGE (a:Sender { name: row.From, domain: row.Sender_Sub_Fld, datetime: datetime(replace(row.DateTime, ' ', 'T'))})
MERGE (b:Recipient { name: row.To, datetime: datetime(replace(row.DateTime, ' ', 'T'))})
WITH a,b,row
WHERE row.Url = "false" AND row.FileHash = "false"
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, row.Outcome2, {}, {}, b) YIELD rel as rel1
RETURN a,b
```

As you can see I have added the datetime property to both the `Sender` and `Recipient` nodes.  I would like to add this property to the relationship.  The problem that I am running into is that my property is created using `apoc.merge.relationship()` so that I can create the name based on the outcome in the rows column.

Can I add something below the `CALL` portion to add the `datetime: datetime(replace(row.DateTime, ' ', 'T'))` as a property to the relationship?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add properties to relationships in the same `apoc.merge.relationship` call. Here is the signature of that apoc call:

`apoc.merge.relationship(startNode :: NODE?, relationshipType :: STRING?, identProps :: MAP?, props :: MAP?, endNode :: NODE?, onMatchProps = {} :: MAP?) :: (rel :: RELATIONSHIP?)`

So this should work for you:

`CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, row.Outcome2, {}, {datetime:datetime(replace(row.DateTime, ' ', 'T'))}, b, {})`

Remember this will add the `datatime` property only when a new edge gets created. If you set a property in the last argument of `apoc.merge.relationship`, then the property will be added on `MATCH`. If you want to include the property in the `MATCH` part of the `MERGE`, you can set it in the 3rd argument of `apoc.merge.relationship`. For example, if you run

```
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, "CONNECTS_TO", {time: "today"}, {}, b, {})
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, "CONNECTS_TO", {time: "tomorrow"}, {}, b, {})
```

you will end up with two `CONNECTS_TO` edges between `a` and `b`, one with `time: "today"`, and one with `time:"tomorrow"`. But if you run the following instead

```
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, "CONNECTS_TO", {}, {time: "today"}, b, {})
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, "CONNECTS_TO", {}, {time: "tomorrow"}, b, {})
```

You will end up with only one `CONNECTS_TO` edge that has `time: "today"` as its property.

Comment: This works and thank you for the explanation @NonameCurious